# Tensorflow: OOM error while creating multiple models in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, out-of-memory

I have function that creates medium size model, and I have for loop to iterate over dictionary of hyperparameters, each time in loop model with different hyperparameters is created. I'm using GPU for training.
However, after creating 3 models I get Out Of Memory error:
RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: failed to allocate memory

I tried putting

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

before and after creating model but it does nothing.

pseudocode:

```
FOR hyperparameter in hyperparameters:
   model = createModel(hyperparameter)
   #do something with model like model.fit()
   Now I want to destroy/clear model (how can I do it?)
```

I dont need to save every model in list or something.

How can I achieve that memory allocation/deallocation so I can test like 100 different models or so?
Thanks

Comment: I am working on something very similar and faced the exact problem. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the model and eventual data you create in the loop:

```py
import gc

for hyperparameter in hyperparameters:
    model = createModel(hyperparameter)
    #do something with model like model.fit()

    # delete model
    del model

    # if you generated/loaded some data/dataset in the loop,
    # delete them too
    del data

    # force the garbage collector to free memory
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: This is CUDA related, I am not sure if deleting / gc.collect() would work.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. However, now when I try to call model.fit() I still get out of memory error, Im loading data to fit just once before for loop. Any possible solution?

Comment: The data is in `numpy`  format? If so, consider to use a `tf.data.Dataset` instead: the OOM can be related to the data causing some memory leak. Also, are you saving some intermediate `tf.Tensor` at each iterations:notice that tensors are stored on the GPU memory too, so if you're collecting results do that on CPU.